# bind_param() не хочет передавать значение для id

Tags: php, mysql

Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 6 by reference in E:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\miacum1.php on line 41

Чтобы я не менял все равно он выдает эту ошибку на строке bind_param, где 6 значение равно Null или другому значению. Я даже новую таблицу создал для проверки, все равно никак...

```
<?php
    require_once 'login.php';
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $stmt = $db_server->prepare('INSERT INTO book VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)');
        $stmt->bind_param('ssssisi', $author, $title, $category, $year, null , Now(), $isbn);
        $author = $_POST[author];
        $title = $_POST[title];
        $category = $_POST[category];
        $year = $_POST[year];
        $isbn = $_POST[isbn];
        $stmt->execute();
        printf("%d Row inserted.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);
        $stmt->close();
        $db_server->close();
    }
    echo <<<_END
<form action="miacum1.php" method="post"> <pre>
author   <input type="text" name="author" />
title    <input type="text" name="title" />
category <input type="text" name="category" />
year     <input type="text" name="year" />
isbn     <input type="text" name="isbn" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="ADD book" /> </pre>
</form>
_END;
?>
```

[image: Вот скриншот таблицы в базе данных]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $stmt = $db_server->prepare('INSERT INTO book VALUES(?,?,?,?,null,now(),?)');
    $stmt->bind_param('ssssi', $author, $title, $category, $year, $isbn);
```

Comment: Спасибооо =)                                                                                               Удачи вам!

Comment: Тут не всё так однозначно. `now` в mysql в общем случае может быть не эквивалентно `now` в php